# flash[:notice].should_not be_nil failed in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is rspec code for controller:

```
it "should render edit if update was not saved" do
  item = Factory(:lease_item)
  session[:corp_head] = true
  post 'update', {:id => item.id, :name => 'nil'}
  flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
  response.should render 'edit'    
end
```

The update in controller is:

```
  def update
    if (eng? && dept_head?) || corp_head? || ceo?
      @lease_item = LeaseItem.find(params[:id])
      @lease_item.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
      if @lease_item.update_attributes(params[:lease_item], :as => :roles_update)

        #redirect
        redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=Lease item updated successfully")
      else
        #back to new
        render 'edit', :notice => "Item NOT updated"
      end
    else
      #back to previous page
      redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=NO right to update lease item")
    end    
  end
```

Here is the error code from rspec:

```
  1) LeaseItemsController GET 'update' should render edit if update was not saved
     Failure/Error: flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
```

"Item NOT updated" was expected in flash. However why there is nothing with flash[:notice]? Or how to rspec there is a message with render 'edit', :notice => 'Item NOT updated'

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Here is change in controller:

```
      ...........
      else
        #back to new
        flash[:notice] = "Item NOT updated"
        render 'edit'
      end
      .........
```

Here is the rspec code which passes:

```
   it "should render edit if update was not saved" do
      item = Factory(:lease_item)
      session[:corp_head] = true
      post 'update', {:id => item.id, :lease_item => {:name => 'nil'}}
      flash.should_not be_nil
      response.should render_template(:action=> "edit")  
    end
```

It did not work if using flash[:notice].should_not be_nil (or .. flash.now[:notice]...). The error is Got nil which is the same as before. Also response.should render 'edit' (or ... render :action => 'edit') did not pass as well. The error is NameError or NoMethodError. Not sure why.

Comment: You're sending "Item NOT updated" in the variable `notice` to the `edit` partial, but are you actually setting `flash[:notice]`?

Comment: How to set up flash[:notice]?

Comment: there is no render 'foo', :notice => "blah"...read the docs. Use flash[:notice] = "Item NOT updated" then render 'edit'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your else to:

```
else
  #back to new
  flash[:notice] = "Item NOT updated"
  render 'edit'
end
```

Comment: rspec still returns error: Failure/Error: flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil

Comment: Really ? do response.should render 'edit' and then do flash[:notice].should_not be_nil.

Comment: I don't get it do you still have an issue? you need to add render_views at the beggining of your rspec tests.                                                                                        .                                                                         describe LeaseItemsController do  
  render_views                                                                                                                               
                                                                                   Also create a file in the views/leaseitems/edit.html.haml (or erb)

Answer (score 0):

First, I can't see where exactly you set the `flash` in your code.

Whatever, replace:

```
  post 'update', {:id => item.id, :name => 'nil'}
```

with:

```
  post 'update', {:id => item.id, :lease_item => { :name => 'nil' } }
```

Comment: :notice is included in the render command. It ends up in flash, doesn't it?

Comment: There is no error with both post command. Is there a real difference between those two post?

Comment: :notice is not in the render command. Render is also not a command...look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d5fd83f4c7f01cc1761783408267cce4d5da1946/actionpack/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb#L16